# Adding a column of data

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

Not been able to find something that matches what I am setting out to teach myself, so here goes:

I have added a column (called **status**) to an existing table (called **fruit**). All values in this new column are currently null. Other columns in this table are **id** (primary key int(11) ) and **fruitname**.

My question is this:

Is there a command I can use to populate this column in one go? Or do I need to update each row one by one?

Ideally I am looking for something that populates columns in the same way **insert** does to rows. Something where I can specify the table and column name and then list the values to fill down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the new column `status` to have same value for all records like `Fresh` then you can do it in one go like

```
update fruit set status = 'fresh'
```

Else, you have no other way than performing an `UPDATE` row by row and populate the `status` column value for each fruit record.